# How to use CompletableFuture with AWS Glue job status?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, completable-future, aws-glue

I have a requirement where I need to get the status of AWS Glue crawler, which is an async request, and based on when the jobs get completed, I would fire certain events. The catch here is that I do not want to use polling. On looking further, AWS docs suggests to use `CompletableFuture` object to deal with async request in AWS. But when I try to use, I am not able to form `CompletableFuture` object as it gives me Type mismatch. I have this code :

```
GetCrawlerMetricsRequest metricsRequest =
        new GetCrawlerMetricsRequest().withCrawlerNameList(Arrays.asList("myJavaCrawler"));
    GetCrawlerMetricsResult jsonOb = awsglueClient.getCrawlerMetrics(metricsRequest);
    CompletableFuture<GetCrawlerMetricsResult> futureResponse = CompletableFuture<GetCrawlerMetricsResult>awsglueClient.getCrawlerMetricsAsync(metricsRequest);
```

But `futureResponse` object shows error stating `FutureTask cannot be casted to CompletableFuture`.

I am following the approach given [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/basics-async.html)

I am not sure how can I make this working. Based on this `futureResponse` object, I can then use `.whenApply` function to trigger the certain job which I want to execute such as pushing the above response into a Kafka Queue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using AWS SDK v1 when the doc you mentioned shows how to do it using v2 (which has 'Developer Preview' status, so it's not recommended for production). [Here is a doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/basics-async.html) showing how to make async calls in v1

For your use case I would recommend another approach. Glue [posts few types of events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#glue-event-types) and one of them is "Crawler Succeeded". So you can create a [CloudWatch rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Rule.html) to catch these events and trigger a lambda which will make a call to start appropriate job

Comment: I had that idea in mind, but I am trying to make it as cloud agnostic as possible so that I can run it across multiple cloud platforms using similar type of functionality. Like I would use Glue in AWS, similar kind of functionality in Azure, Google cloud and so on.